# Max scroll height of <div> Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I am currently working on a custom function for a jQuery plugin. We want to mimic iOS' bouncing and snapping (so when the user scrolls up too much, the viewport allows it, and then bounces back down), and similarly when the user reaches the bottom, we snap it back to the maximum position (hope that makes sense).

I am using `translate3d()` to allow for hardware acceleration, and simply setting the y value accordingly. This works well, but I would like a method with which I can calculate the maximum valid y value for the `translate3d` function, so we can easily set the scroller to the bottom by simply setting this value.

Does anyone know how I might achieve this? I have access to the following dimensions:

- container innerHeight
- container outerHeight
- container scrollHeight
- wrapper innerHeight
- wrapper outerHeight
- wrapper scrollHeight

And here's the markup for the scrolling `div`:

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
        <!-- My Content is in Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```